# ODE with strange initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $k_0$ be it's fixed point (not necessarily the only one). Prove that:
>
> - $f'(k_0)<1$ implies that there are no solutions to the equation $y'=f(\frac{y}{t})$ adjacent to the line $y=k_0t$ in point $t=0$
> - $f'(k_0)>1$ implies that there are infinitely many of such solutions.

**My attempt:**

What we have to do here is to determine the number of solutions of the Cauchy equation $y'=f(\frac{y}{t})$ given that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=k_0$.

We can substitute $z=y-tk_0$, which leads to $z' + k_0 = f(k_0 + \frac{z}{t})$. Now we can expand $f$ into Taylor series: $z' + k_0 = f(k_0) + \frac{z}{t}f'(k_0) + r(\frac{z}{t})$, where $r$ is a residue function. It reduces to $z' = \frac{z}{t}f'(k_0) + r(\frac{z}{t})$. Here the problem emerges: we cannot control the $\frac{z}{t}$, we don't know whether it's big or small. If we knew, the natural next substitution would be
$u=\frac{z}{t}$ and it would give us $u't = u(f'(k_0)-1) + r(u)$, hence

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{t} = \int\dfrac{du}{u(f'(k_0)-1)+r(u))}$$.
From now we can easily say that for all $t>0$ the integral on the left side explodes to $+\infty$ so assuming $r(u)$ is small around $0$ gives us that it must be $u(f'(k_0)-1)>0$ locally. So knowing that, for example, $0<u$ and $u$ is small for some $t\in [0,\epsilon]$ we could deduce that there's no solution for $f'(k_0)<1$. But I don't know how to control the behavior of $u$.

Thank you for your feedback and I'd like to ask for some hint first because that's my homework.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I think I've found it: $f$ is differentiable hence $y$ (and of course $z$) is at least $C^1$. Now we can launch de l'Hospital rule to compute: $u(0)$. We have $u(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{z}{t} \overset{\mathrm{H}}{=} \lim_{t\to 0} z'(t) = 0$. Then it seems quite easy to proceed (although I have to think for a while on it).